# Angular Routing Curriosity for Parameters in the middle of the route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

For example, can you have something like 
dashboard/items/:id

Then from that point have another layer added on top of that with a separate Module? For example

dashboard/items/:id/itemInfo

Running into 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Haven't found anything strictly saying that You cannot, but haven't found any examples of it either.

Comment: Yes you can. This error is irrelevant to that question. If you need help on it, please provide code.

Comment: Found that my issue was with the use of pathmatch: 'full', while loading children of that path. I've since fixed the issue, sorry with the late foot note.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
{
    path: 'dashboard/items/:id/itemInfo',
    component: 'ItemInfoComponent',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Comment: Can you share how to get value id in ItemInfoComponent?
Its shows me route not matched error when /dashboard/items/44545454/itemInfo.